# USB is not recognized by MultiSystem in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I want to dual boot Windows alongside Ubuntu. I formatted the USB flash drive using the terminal by following the instructions from a YouTube video. Then I booted my flash drive with Ubuntu, and now I use the [MultiSystem](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/) application to dual boot Windows alongside Ubuntu, but MultiSystem does not recognize my USB flash drive. Maybe something should be done after formatting my USB to make it recognizable for MultiSystem to be able to dual boot.

Comment: I wanna install window alongside ubuntu.Currently I am on ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/)